# Ambiguity between methods of calculating quartiles. Which method is more correct?

Tags: statistics, percentile

I am having confusion between two methods of calculating the first quartiles.

Let me explain by an example:

$A = [1,2,3,4,5]$

**The method that I know:**

To find the first quartile in the list above I first find the median = $3$ that is the 3rd element.

Now I split the list in the following fashion:

$(1,2)$

$3$

$(4,5)$

Now we take the list $(1,2)$ and we find the media between them that is $(1+2)/2 = 1.5$.

So according to my calculation the first quartile $Q_1 = 1.5$.

**The nearest rank method([Found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Worked_examples_of_the_nearest-rank_method))**

$ n = \lceil\frac{P}{100} \times N\rceil$

So for the above list the $0.25$ percentile or the first quartile $Q_1$ will be

$\lceil \frac{25}{100} \times {5} \rceil = 2$

which is 2nd position.

**So which is correct $1.5$ or $2$ ? Or does chosing any of them is fine ?**

If I am correct in my original calculation why am I getting a difference between the 2 methods.

This different from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2697495/407302) since my question involves in understanding which method is more correct.

Comment: There are varying definitions for what a 'quartile' is ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile#Method_1)). Check which method your teacher/instructor uses and stick to that.

Comment: @TobyMak Thats my entire point. Why are there varying definitions for the same thing ? Shouldn't there be one correct answer ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://web.mnstate.edu/peil/MDEV102/U4/S36/S363.html) and many other pages, the first quartile is defined as the middle number of the lower half of the data set.

However, the meaning of 'lower half' is ambiguous. This is because in the situation where there is an odd number of data points, dividing by half will give a number which is not an integer. Therefore, one method excludes the median (a set of $\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$ numbers), and another method includes the median (a set of $\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil$ numbers).

From what I have seen, the first method is by far the most common method, so what you are doing is not wrong. This is because the method taught in the classroom teaches from a more theoretical perspectives, and so the data sets are small to facilitate computation.

Method 2 seems to be more useful in applied mathematics, such as when you have a large dataset. In this case, there is a finer distinction between the $25$th percentile and the $26$th percentile, so in this case calculating the exact $25$th percentile would give a different answer.

And of course, when there are an even number of data points, there is no ambiguity, so both methods give the same result.

Comment: So which is more correct ? There can't be two correct methods given two seperate answers can they ?

Comment: Both are correct, but the first method is (by far) the most commonly used. As to why the definition hasn't been made more rigorous, there probably are situations when it is preferable to use one over the other (programming).

Comment: so both are correct ? Which cases would you want to use one method over the other. This is really confusing.

Comment: I think it is easier for programmers to use the second definition. But for the definition in pure mathematics, the first definition is the only correct definition.

Comment: I appreciate your frankness but I am unable to understand why would two different answers given by 2 different method be correct? Does the field of statistics tolerate wrong answers to a certain extent ?

Comment: I just read Ethan's answer on this other [question](How to calculate the percentile, in data NOT grouped?). It turns out when the data set is large, the percentile definition is more useful as there is a distinction between $25 \%$ and $26 \%$. But for smaller datasets, your first definition makes the most sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98484/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-ng-newbie).